# Transfer Money From AMEX to PayPal

Tags: paypal

How can I transfer money from AMEX to PayPal. PayPal has an "Add Fund" option, but it didn't really work for me.

The error I got was:

> PayPal does not currently offer the
>   ability to add funds from your bank
>   account.
>
> When you make a payment, PayPal
>   charges the buyer's credit card and
>   instantly credits the seller's PayPal
>   account.

Comment: Instead of saying *"it didn't work"*, can you tell us exactly what happened, why it didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't transfer money from a credit card to PayPal. However, you can add your credit card as a money source to fund purchases through PayPal. Your credit card number will not be given to the merchant, the charge will come from PayPal, so your card is still secure from online fraudsters.

To link a credit card as a funds source, go to `My Account` / `Profile` / `Add or Edit Credit Card`.

Answer (score 2):

Paypal will not give you a cash advance against your own credit card. You can pay someone else with your credit card - or you can accept a payment from someone else's credit card - but you can't charge $100 against your own credit card to get a $100 Paypal balance.

I think Paypal has pretty low limits on accepting credit card payments for people who aren't set up as merchants with Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal doesn't like it, but you can always set up a second account pointing to a different money source (such as your checking account) and transfer money that way.

Also, if you are just trying to float the amount. You can probably just sign up for PayPal buyer credit. That way you can make the $100 purchase and then pay it off however you want.

Comment: This will cost, no?